# openParentApplication method is missing from watch os 4

Tags: ios, watchkit

how do I awake parent app from watch app when parent app is not running state.

Comment: Please read how to post a question on StackOverflow. Your problem will be solved once its clearly stated.

Answer (score 0):

That method is only available in `watchOS1` as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619531-openparentapplication) clearly states.

From `watchOS2+`, Watch apps are no longer considered just extensions of the `iOS` app and hence you cannot open the connected `iOS` application from your Watch app.

Comment: so @Dávid Pásztor what you suggest ,if hosting app is killed and watch  continuesly sending data. how to  receive data if hosting app is not in background or foreground.

Comment: You simply cannot. You should check in your watch app whether the iOS app is running or not and if it is not running, then save the data locally and send it once the iOS app becomes available.